# Disable reload on angular factory object

Tags: angularjs, routes, factory

I have a test with a large number of questions (168) so I'm using routing and a factory to create an object that holds all the questions and answers of the test, but I have a problem, everything works great while the user doesn't hit reload, when the user hits reload, all the questions and answers get lost.

I tried the same with cache factory but the same happens the object is lost on reload.

Here's my code:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('psicoTestsApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/intro', {
                templateUrl: 'partialsKuder/kuderIntro.html',
                controller: 'IntroCtrl'
            }).
            when('/detalles/:paginaId', {
                templateUrl: 'partialsKuder/kuderDetail.html',
                controller: 'PreguntaDetalleCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/intro'
            });
    }]);

    app.factory("appInfo", function(){
        return {};
    });


    app.controller('IntroCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'appInfo', function ($scope, $http, appInfo) {
        $scope.appInfo = appInfo;

        $http.get('preguntas.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.appInfo.preguntas = data;
        });

    }]);

    app.controller('PreguntaDetalleCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', 'appInfo', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, appInfo) {
        $scope.appInfo = appInfo;
        $scope.preguntas = $scope.appInfo.preguntas;

        $scope.paginaId = parseInt($routeParams.paginaId);
        $scope.siguiente = $scope.paginaId + 1;

        $scope.pregunta1 = $scope.preguntas[($scope.paginaId * 4) + 0];
        $scope.pregunta2 = $scope.preguntas[($scope.paginaId * 4) + 1];
        $scope.pregunta3 = $scope.preguntas[($scope.paginaId * 4) + 2];
        $scope.pregunta4 = $scope.preguntas[($scope.paginaId * 4) + 3];

    }]);

})();
```

So is there a way to make it like a cookie? so I won't lost de info on reload? or can I disable reload while in the form?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to take a look at [ngStorage](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage)

Comment: Thanks, ng storage worked weird so I tried ng-cookies but the info ended up being to big for a cookie, so I finally changed everything to go to the server each time.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as PSL indicated, you can't really do anything about the user hitting reload on the page. That's similar to a computer being rebooted, or an application being restarted. If you store session information somehow (ngStorage is a good way, or you could use a session cookie, or you could store on the backend), you can't really persist data across reload events.